# Does a Windows Server 2012 FRSM auto-applied quota at a root folder mean the root folder has a cumulative quota equal to all subfolder quotas?

Tags: windows-server-2012, quota, directory

I've done some reading on TechNet and run a few searches for this answer, but so far haven't found anything. I have a root folder with 9 subfolders, and I assigned an auto apply template to the root folder which propagates to the subfolders. I want all 9 subfolders to each have a 5 GB quota, which to me means the root actually has a 45 GB quota. However, in FSRM, it appears that the root only has a 5 GB total quota to be shared between the subfolders. My question is, does the actual root quota equal the auto apply template quota (in this case 5 GB), or is it a cumulative total of all 9 subfolders (which would equal 45 GB)?

Comment: Solved my own question... I set up a test root folder with some subfolders and applied an auto apply template to the root. The root "quota" is indeed a cumulative total of all subfolders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What really happens is the root folder has 5 GB quota, and each subfolder has 5 GB quota.
So you can't actually have a 6 GB file in the root folder, but you can have a 5 GB file per subfolder.

This means because the subfolder has an explicit quota defined, the files within this subfolder only count to the quota of the subfolder, and not the parent folder.

So in your case yes, each folder has 5 GB quota with a total of 45 GB for these folders.